# Netbeans: Remote project w/source files over SSH?

Tags: netbeans, ssh, remote-debugging

Is it possible to set up a remote `NetBeans` C++ project where the source files are *only* accessible via SSH?

My project needs to build on a Linux box, but I'd like to develop it on a Windows machine.

Checking out the code via SVN to my Windows machine is not an option since there are a few files that differ only by case, and NTFS is not case sensitive (unfortunately, I can not change them).

I'm well aware that Windows can be kind-of forced be case-aware and the ideal solution is to just re-name those file to something sane.

However, I'm just trying to solve this using NetBeans.  Since it's a remote project anyway, why bother to keep any files locally.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently, no. In general programming files with different cases of the same name is a bad practice.

You can enable case sensitivity in Windows - you may need to have a Professional version or better.

- For Windows XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817921
- For Windows 7: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732389.aspx
- See also: [Windows Services for Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX)

Another solution would be to setup VNC/RDP on the remote Unix system. The overall solution should be to conform to a better file naming convention:

> - Programmer 1: "Hey man, take a look at noCamelCase.cs - I just rewrote it."
> - Programmer 2: "Um, nocamelcase.cs is blank."

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing remote builds with Netbeans. The first, the project is stored locally. You just create a regular project and on the 2nd page of the wizard you specify the network directory with the source and the remote build host. I've used this for Solaris client to Linux server, but not from Windows as we don't have the mounts exported by SMB. This uses ssh and some shared lib interposers to get the build info.

The second way is to create a remote project. In this case the project is created on the remote host and date is copied on demand to the client. I've only doe a few tests with this as I preferred the first method as it had much better latency.

Lastly, you could either use vnc or install X on your windows machine and do everything on the Linux machine.